# Search for string in database according to string relevance and string order

Tags: php, mysql

I have an example of SQL search statements, where I try to find the part of strings in order, in relevance first. So it first searches the full string of "one two three", and then moves on to "one two", and then "two three", and then eventually all the way to one words, but it never searches backwards. Only in order. So, for example, it would never search for "three two one", only "one two three", and I'm wondering if it's possible to combine all of these single query statements into a single query? Thank you.

```
$text1 = "one";
$text2 = "two";
$text3 = "three";

SELECT text FROM tableName WHERE text LIKE "$text1 $text2 $text3"  
SELECT text FROM tableName WHERE text LIKE "$text1 $text2"
SELECT text FROM tableName WHERE text LIKE "$text2 $text3"
SELECT text FROM tableName WHERE text LIKE "$text1" 
SELECT text FROM tableName WHERE text LIKE "$text2" 
SELECT text FROM tableName WHERE text LIKE "$text3"
```

Comment: fulltext search with relevance is what you really want here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can search for them and then order by relevance.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT text
FROM tableName
WHERE text LIKE "$text1" OR
      text LIKE "$text2" OR
      text LIKE "$text3" 
ORDER BY (text LIKE "$text1 $text2 $text3") DESC,
         (text LIKE "$text1 $text2") DESC,
         (text LIKE "$text2 $text3") DESC,
         (text LIKE "$text1" ) DESC,
         (text LIKE "$text2" ) DESC,
         (text LIKE "$text3" ) DESC
```